# Converting German format numbers to the international format

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL, and i have a small question.

I have a `varchar`column with a numbers in German format, and i need to convert the format to the international one (without comma), and convert the column to `float`.

For example:

```
4,33 --> 4.11
33.000.000,01 --> 33000000.01
77.000,00 --> 77000
```

Is there a function that can do this conversation? If so, what is it? I didn't find such as function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the varchar value with the TO_NUMBER function into a NUMBER value:

```
select to_number('4,33', '999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') from dual union
select to_number('33.000.000,01', '999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') from dual union
select to_number('70.000,00', '999G999G999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.''') from dual
```